# How to create image page control similar to Photos app in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to create a page control like photos app. When swiping an image in centre view the bottom view also swipes automatically and expanding. I want to create similar to that. Any help.....

Comment: You'll need to create it based on your own collectionViews, or you may find a suitable third-party library for what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Collection View, and change item Size based on position

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I'm already using the centre view as collectionView. And what I want is, When I swipe the image, the bottom view should also change simultaneously. Please check the Photos App in iPhone or simulator.

Comment: I did, and I repeat that collection view is the answer. Add a second one, and listen to "scrollViewDidScroll" to move both collection simultaneously. Already made it in my apps

Comment: I've done it using two collectionViews. But, When I resize the particular cell in centre, the spacing in between the cells not working properly. Can you help me out...

Comment: You have to deal with UICollectionViewFlowLayout and play with layoutAttributesForElements

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/alberto093/ImageUI  library for creating your custom layout